# Microsoft Graph updating event attachment is not updated in attendees invitations

Tags: java, http, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft graph api to send event invitation to attendees when I update event by
**PATCH [https://graph.microsoft.com/me/events/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/me/events/%7Bid%7D)**
the event attachments is updated in organizer but not in sent invitations

***is it because the invitation is received on attendance main calendar and I'm creating it on another specific calendar by the organizer ?***
Note: in adding event step I added the attachments first then sent the invitations it was a bug in the api that attachments aren't updated after invitations are sent?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) first create an event and then update the attachment. It will be updated for all attendees.

Comment: Are you still looking for help?